# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Users\\Public\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll'

Tags: sql-server, apache, httpd.conf

Today I received a new development and a new production server. I have installed my XAMPP on my dev server in the `C:\\Users\\Public` directory. I have installed the Apache server and changed it so that it will be executed as a different, less privileged user. After that, I cloned my webapp project that connects to AD and a MS SQL server.

Bear in mind that all of this is already working on my previous development server.

Now, I copied the `php.ini` file from my `php` directory into the `php` directory of the new server.

When executing the server, I get these errors in my apache error log:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Users\\Public\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Users\\Public\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

When trying to use sqlsrv_connect, which also works perfectly on the old dev server, I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\Users\Public\xampp\htdocs\sql_functions.php:18
```

After typing this, I attempted to copy the entire `ext` directory over. This was a bad mistake:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Users\\Public\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_bz2.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Users\\Public\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_curl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Users\\Public\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_fileinfo.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Users\\Public\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_gd2.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Users\\Public\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_gettext.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Users\\Public\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Users\\Public\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_mbstring.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Users\\Public\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_exif.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Users\\Public\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Users\\Public\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_mysqli.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Users\\Public\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_pdo_sqlite.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Users\\Public\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Users\\Public\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Users\\Public\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_openssl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm using a different Apache version.

New server: 2.4.26

Old server: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.28

Edit: I just compared the two `httpd.conf` files. Except for the paths and about 7 lines about a `<IfModule headers_module>`, there is no difference.

Comment: You can't plug random DLLs. Your extensions need to match your PHP setup: architecture (32 or 64 bit), compiler (VC) and thread-safety.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the hint. I've installed a backup copy of XAMPP into a different folder and copied the good DLL's over, now I'm back to the original problem of `php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll` and `php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll` not loading. I'm pretty sure that these are for the 32-bit Architecture which I'm using, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it!

I downloaded the most recent release from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases).

Then I simply edited php.ini to point to the newest file, which was, in this case:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll
```

Comment: Oh well... I assumed you already new that `56` in `php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll` stands for `PHP/5.6.x`. You didn't even mention you were upgrading PHP to a newer version.

Comment: That's because I didn't notice that I had upgraded. I simply downloaded the most recent version of XAMPP and didn't notice that it had a newer version of PHP integrated. Mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Try to x64 or x86 versions. I solved this method.